# disable all chunk evaluation but keep inline evaluation

Tags: r, knitr

I want do disable all chunk evaluation but keep inline evaluation via `\Sexpr`. Setting `eval` globally to `FALSE` like this

```
  \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   <<setup, include=FALSE>>=
   opts_chunk$set(eval= FALSE)
   @

   \Sexpr{"is not displayed"} bummer.
   \end{document}
```

also affects `\Sexpr`.

p.s.: I searched for all subsets of [knitr],\Sexpr, eval. I just hope the formatting is correct

p.s.: I don't want to set eval to 1.

Comment: This will be the default behavior in the next version of knitr: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md You may install knitr from Github and test the development version.